# ios application not published using adobe flash professional cc on mac

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, air, flash-cs6

i am trying to publish an ios application using adobe flash cc on mac and flash professional cs6 on windows.

when i  publish my application using cs6 ( air sdk 3.7, air sdk 3.6 ) on windows  ipa is created and installed only on jail-break phone and when i try to install jailed phone its simply shows application failed to install.

when i start to publish with flash professional CC on mac (Size of Ram is 768MB) ipa is not created but the following errors are shown:

```
"Restore windows
 The application “java” unexpectedly quit while trying to restore its windows.
 Do you want to try to restore its windows again?"
```

and

```
"ADT quit unexpectedly while using the libjvm.dylib plug-in.
 Click Reopen to open the application again.
 Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple."
```

and at last a error report

if anyone face this issue or have sorted out this please let me know.
thanks

Virender

Error report:

```
Process:           java [1175]
Path:              /usr/bin/java
Identifier:        net.java.openjdk.cmd
Version:           1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:         X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:    sh [1174]
PlugIn Path:       /Applications/Adobe Flash CC/Adobe Flash CC.app/Contents/jre/jre1.7.0_10.jre/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.d ylib
PlugIn Identifier: libjvm.dylib
PlugIn Version:    ??? (???)
Date/Time:         2013-07-11 22:10:34.716 -0700
OS Version:        Mac OS X 10.7.4 (11E53)
Report Version:    9
Interval Since Last Report:          37146 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           41
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  6085 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   41
Anonymous UUID:    CDBA110A-A463-40BB-9E1F-2321B9E94AFE
Crashed Thread:    18  Java: Java2D Queue Flusher
Exception Type:    EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000003b0
VM Regions Near 0x3b0:
```

Comment: Do you have all the correct profiles setup, because to mee it sound like you are trying to run an app on a device that is not register in the profile you are using to build your app.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution you can try using IfunBox with install IPA on a non jailbreack phone. By the way i had the same probrem, I was unable to instal my IPA on a non Jailbreack phone but wen i upload to Apple every thing goes fine! One of the reasons of the intalation fail could be that u didnt mach the license id and software name wen um create the IPA.

Comment: On my case I found that the file that apple orders (the certificate created by the User) when making the certificates for the app had incorrect data. I had used on windows tools to generate the file. With that fixed, the applications installs on the device normally without jailbreack. And try use AIR 3.8

Comment: As I said before you can use Ifun to install IPA on Iphones NON JAILBREACK devide or for iOS 6.1.3 use this Chinese -link below-. I hope you can test your applications while not solve your problem. http://kuaiyong.com/eg_web/index.html